# Database error 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm getting the error below. What am I doing wrong?

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' i1 int(20), i2 int(20), avg int(20), ext int(20), tot int(20), `month' at line 4

```
create table `marks`(
  `sno` int(20),
  `sub` varchar,
  `i1` int(20),
  `i2` int(20),
  `avg` int(20),
  `ext` int(20),
  `tot` int(20),
  `month` varchar,
  `year` varchar
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the max length of your `varchar` strings. For instance like this

```
varchar(20)
```

Also `year` and `month` should be `int` and not a string:

```
create table `marks`
(
  `sno` int,
  `sub` varchar(20),
  `i1` int,
  `i2` int,
  `avg` int,
  `ext` int,
  `tot` int,
  `month` int,
  `year` int
);
```

And you should define a primary key. Looks like you better take a basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: Then delete your "answer"